# Best way to overwrite files after a specific number are in a directory in python

Tags: python, xen

Ok, so I wrote a python program which creates backups of virtual machines on a virtual machine server and saves them onto an NFS. I want to make it so that only the most recent 10 backups are saved. So after 10 backups, start over writing the first, second, third, etc. What is the best approach for this? All i could think of is to have a text file which contains all the log information and a current state. Is there a better route? This is for Xen Server which uses python. thanks

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a simple txt file each time a new backup is made?

Could be something like this:  backup_ddmmyy_h_m.txt in an backup_cache directory?
And then before you make a new backup you simply check if you have 10 backup txt files, and delete the oldest one.

Comment: Cool, please accept the answer if it answers you question :)